# Replace Mongrel with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mongrel

I am new to Rails, so bear with me, I need to have apache tomcat as application server. How do i configure that by replacing the default Mongrel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, to deploy a rails app on tomcat, you need jRuby (a ruby version that runs on JVM).

I'll suggest you to read this tutorial to make an idea: http://thenice.tumblr.com/post/133345213/deploying-a-rails-application-in-tomcat-with-jruby-a

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.joyent.com/accelerators:apache_rails_mongrel

helps you